# veracrypt cannot be installed in kubuntu 23.04

Tags: kubuntu, veracrypt, 23.04

```
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 veracrypt : Depends: libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Above is the error which appears on trying to install the veracrypt deb file in kubuntu 23.04. I am trying to install veracrypt version 1.25.9 downloaded from official webside. I also tried to install the gui version using the veracrypt generic installer, and it too seems not working. Tried installing libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 using apt, but apt failed to find the package.
What should i do ?

Comment: I tried installing the .deb from here https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5/download

but that also failed due to unmet dependencies

Answer (score 3):

This is very much a VeraCrypt problem, and not an Ubuntu problem.

You'll note they have builds for Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04, 21.04, 21.10 and 22.04, but not 23.04. I'd recommend one of the following:

- Using a VeraCrypt supported release of Ubuntu
- Use the "Generic installer" available on the VeraCrypt download page
- Contact VeraCrypt and request a 23.04 release build.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the exact version of the library, as well as for other products such as AppImage Apps

```
sudo apt install libfuse2
```

Then download the `veracrypt-1.25.9-setup.tar.bz2` file from the veracrypt repository, then extract the file and run the tool as follows:

```
sudo ./veracrypt-1.25.9-setup-gtk3-gui-x64
```

When prompted do not install it but click on "Extract .tar Package File".The installation package is extracted on `/tmp`.
Extract tar file:

```
tar xvf veracrypt_1.25.9_amd64.tar.gz
```

The `usr` folder is created on the extraction folder, in its entirety must be copied as follows:

```
sudo cp -R usr/* /usr/
```

Now you can run veracrypt from the command line or from the application menu

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).